# cakephp tcpdf image error [Image] Unable to get image

Tags: cakephp, tcpdf

i am trying to figure out this weird issue using TCPDF and CakePHP.

the fact is that i am able to output a "static" image like this

```
$this->Image(WWW_ROOT.'/img/logo-infiniti.png', 15, 15);
```

but when i use cakephp instruction for images it doesn't work anymore

```
echo $this->Image->resize($line['Line']['UploadImage'][0]['name'], 100, 100);
```

and i get this error

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get image: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/configurator/files/cache/a/a/79x100_1316533443.jpg
```

any help will be very appreciated...thanks!

Comment: i think so, because if i use the same code without TCPDF `echo $this->Image->resize($line['Line']['UploadImage'][0]['name'], 100, 100);`

it outputs the image correctly

Answer (score 0):

use chmode() function to give permission Applications/MAMP/htdocs/configurator/files/cache to 777