# Unable to get the size of the image ( codeigniter , tcpdf , php )

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3, tcpdf

I have a problem when trying to show picture in tcpdf using codeigniter,

This is my pdf view:

```
$base_url=base_url();

// NON-BREAKING ROWS (nobr="true")

$tbleauproduct = <<<EOD
<br /><br /><br />
<table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>picture</th>
        <th>Product name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><img src="$base_url/assets/$picture" /></td>
        <td>$name</td>
        <td>$price</td>
        <td>$qty</td>
    </tr>
</table>
EOD;

$pdf->writeHTML($tbleauproduct, true, false, true, false, '');
```

and this is the result:

```
TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: http://localhost:8888/open_bay//assets/130501153059-htc-one-1024x576.jpeg
```

Comment: PDF is not an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TCPDF error :Unable to get the size of the image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060947/tcpdf-error-unable-to-get-the-size-of-the-image)

Comment: Avoid posting images of code.  Always post code as text.  I have replaced your image for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_path = base_url().'assets/130501153059-htc-one-1024x576.jpeg';
$size = filesize($file_path);
```

Comment: I use this method but I found this problem   : Message: filesize(): stat failed for http://localhost:8888/open_bay/assets/130501153059-htc-one-1024x576.jpeg

Comment: Code-only answers can be improved by supplying an explanation or perhaps links to official documentation.  Answers don't just help the OP to resolve an issue, they help future SO researchers to quickly solve their issues.  Make every post the highest quality that you can and you will stand to gain more rep points from upvotes.